# How to access Default Idempotent Repository map from java dsl?

Tags: apache-camel

I am newbie to Apache Camel. How can i access Camel Default Idempotent Repository map in Java DSL.

Route:

```
from("file://C:/folderA?noop=true")
.to("file://C:/folderB")
.end();
```

When i say noop=true in route, then idempotent will be true. Now i need to get Idempotent map in java dsl. Please tell me how to access this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the underlying map, you should specify your own `idempotentRepository` bean. Using the existing `MemoryIdempotentRepository` should be pretty easy.

```
//Instantiate repository and get map
IdempotentRepository<String> repo = MemoryIdempotentRepository.memoryIdempotentRepository()
Map<String, Object> map = repo.getCache();

//Bind the repo to the Camel Context Registry using the id "repo"
//This changes depending upon how you are running Camel

//In your RouteBuilder...
from("file://C:/folderA?noop=true&idempotentRepository=#repo")
  .to("file://C:/folderB")
  .end();
```

Comment: Any idea how to make the idempotent repository work with the infinispan. The above code you are using the in memory repository, if i am not wrong. I am using camel version 2.21.1. Can you please add a answer on how to make it work with infinispan repository. It will be really helpful for me... !

Comment: I'm not familiar with Infinispan, but the docs at https://camel.apache.org/infinispan.html indicate that if you include the `camel-infinispan` library there's an implementation of the `IdempotentRepository` already written.