# Why java bean is not converted to camel IdempotentRepository when building the endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, javabeans

I've tried this solution but my implementation doesn't seem to work : [How to access Default Idempotent Repository map from java dsl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758934/how-to-access-default-idempotent-repository-map-from-java-dsl)

```
@Bean
@Scope("prototype")
public static IdempotentRepository<String> getMemoryCache() {
    return new MemoryIdempotentRepository();
}
```

and then I try to make a reference to it in my uri, it throws an exception saying this :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: idempotentRepository as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.spi.IdempotentRepository with value #getMemoryCache()
```

.. what I did to build the uri :

```
URIBuilder builder = _INSTANCE.getSourceFolderEndpointUriBuilder(exchange);
builder.setScheme("file");
builder.addParameter("recursive", "true");
builder.addParameter("readLock", "none");
builder.addParameter("idempotentRepository", "#getMemoryCache()");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, 
the bean had to be in a configuration class and then to reference the bean it should not have parentheses.

```
builder.addParameter("idempotentRepository", "#getMemoryCache");
```

Comment: Yes its the name of the bean only, and by default it uses the name of the method. But you can also declare the name explicit in those `@Bean` annotations